# Cannot Read Profile Token

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am using the DNNSharp ActionGrid and would like to filter the Grid using a Token Value. Using DotNet Nuke version 9.2 I have created 2 custom profile fields. One is a text box and I can use this in the SQL where clause using the Token [Profile:Agency]. The second profile field is a list when I try to use this list with the Token [Profile:AgencyList] I get no data returned from the SQL table. When I inspect the SQL query in a trace the Token value being passed to the SQL server is '********' Why can I not get the value of that Profile list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a typo in the query string.  Apparently trying to access a non existing profile field will return the ******** string.

Comment: That'll do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've only had a similar experience, but with the "*******" behaviour, it feels like it might be the same issue.

See the screenshot below - What is the "Default Visibility" of the [Profile:AgencyList] property?

[image]

I've had it in the past where a user outside of a role group is presented with "*******" in place of the profile property data... I wonder if this is similar behaviour when it's going through the SQL query...